# Azure Artifact - Does not build locally - The type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: nuget, artifact

I have a Azure Artifact feed ..
I have all the permissions to that feed.
I have pushed changes wereby a new version is created under the feed.
Everytime, i use that Artifact locally in a solution, i am not able to refer to any of the class files in the nuget package.

Any help on this regard will be much appreciated.